# Migrating 3 million records from Oracle to Elastic search using logstash

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

We are trying to migrate around 3 million records from oracle to Elastic Search using Logstash.
We are applying a couple of jdbc_streaming filters as a part of our logstash script, one to load connecting nested objects and another to run a hierarchical query to load data to another nested object in the index.

We are able to index 0.4 million records in 24 hours. The total size occupied by .4 million records is around 300MB.
We tried multiple approaches to migrate data quickly into elastic from oracle but were not able to achieve desired results.
Please find below the approaches we tried :
1.In the logstash script,
we used jdbc_fetch_size,
jdbc_page_size,
jdbc_paging_enabled,
clean_run parameters,
set pipeline workers to 20 and
pipeline batch size to 125 in logstash.yml file.
2. On the elastic side,
we set the number of replicas to 0,
refresh interval to -1,
tried increasing the value of indices.memory.index_buffer_size parameter, increased number of watcher queues in the elastic.yml file.

We basically googled out and followed various suggestions from this site and others too but nothing seems to work out so far.

We are using a single node elastic setup and neither the DB nor the elastic node are present on the machine from which we are running the logstash script.

Please find below the logstash config file

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => "LIB"
jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "connection url"
jdbc_user => "user"
jdbc_password => "pwd"
statement => "select * from "
}
}

filter{
jdbc_streaming {
jdbc_driver_library => "LIB"
jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "connection url"
jdbc_user => "user"
jdbc_password => "pwd"
#statement => "select claimnumber,claimtype,is_active from claim where policynumber = :policynumber"
parameters => {"policynumber" => "policynumber"}
target => "nested node"
}
stdout { codec => json }
}

filter{
jdbc_streaming {
jdbc_driver_library => "LIB"
jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "connection url"
jdbc_user => "user"
jdbc_password => "pwd"
statement => "select listagg(column name,'/' ) within group(order by column name) from

where LEVEL > 1
start with =:
connect by prior = "
parameters => {"p1" => "p1"}
target => "nested node1"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => [""]
index => "<index_name>"
document_id => "%{doc_id}"
}
}
```

Can you please help us identify bottlenecks and also make suggestions on how to increase indexing performance.

Thank You

Comment: Does is mean, that you are fetching whole data again and again? I can not see how logstash is able to transfer only incremental changes.

Comment: These are not incremental changes. We are trying to do a one-time data transfer assuming there would not be any changes to the Oracle DB.

Comment: 24 hours is really too much. Either there are some latencies on network of maybe ... does you table have any LOB columns? Oracle's protocol usually requires additional roundtrips to handle LOBs.

Comment: There is no LOB's present in the table.  We were able to load data to elastic search using apache nifi in less than an hour. We are pretty new to Apache nifi and are facing some issues while transforming the data and on the other hand, we have logstash scripts ready. It looks like we are missing out on some logstash specific setting but are not sure about what that is :|.. Trying to figure out that :)

Comment: What was your Nifi configuration and what kind of issues do you have with nested fields?

Comment: And another question: Have you tried using [`jdbc_static`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-jdbc_static.html) instead of `jdbc_streaming` in order to speed up the lookups? Or have you tried using [prepared statements](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-jdbc_streaming.html#plugins-filters-jdbc_streaming-prepared_statements) in conjunction with `jdbc_streaming`?

Comment: In Nifi, we are facing issues when we try to append the JSON outputs for two SQL statements. We created a processor for each SQL statement we are trying to execute and are stuck at the step wherein we are to append the output of the second SQL query to the appropriate JSON it belongs to in the first SQL output.

Comment: We haven't explored jdbc_static... We just had a look at the documentation. We would evaluate it and get back. Also when I try to index using logstash, I am getting an error message with code 429 too many requests after a certain limit. But when I load the same using Apache NIfi, we are not getting that error... Any recommended logstash config changes to get over this?