# What are the best ways to do a one time data load from Oracle to Elastic Search

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, logstash, apache-nifi, elastic-stack

We are trying to do a one-time data load from Oracle to Elastic Search.
We have evaluated Logstash but the indexing is taking a lot of time.
We have tried Apache Nifi but are facing difficulty in loading nested objects and computed results in apache Nifi.
We are trying to maintain one-many relations in nested objects(We have an oracle query to fetch these results) and we are also maintaining the result of a hierarchical query as a field in the index.

We are looking for an open-source alternative and an efficient approach to load around 10 tables with 3 million records each from Oracle to Elastic Search.

Please suggest.

Comment: I use Shareplex to replicate Data Changes into Kafka queue. And then from Kafka into Elastic.

Comment: Thank You @ibre5041!
We are looking for opensource options.

Comment: If it's one time work - why not to write script to push data from sql into elastic?

Comment: We tried writing a logstash script with the configuration as mentioned in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62957239/migrating-3-million-records-from-oracle-to-elastic-search-using-logstash?noredirect=1#comment111346100_62957239 
but it is taking a lot of time to load data to elastic.
By script, do we mean a script in java/Python